# Change HTML <head> content using javascript/jquery

Tags: html, head

let's assume that the  content is empty as given below.

```
<head> 

</head>
```

If I want to change it dynamically to

```
<head> 
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

is there anyway that AppInventor can do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can select it and add to it as normal:

```
$('head').append('</script>');
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( ... );
```

**Make DOM element like so:**

```
script=document.createElement('</script>');
script.src='src';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I dont think he might want to use jQuery though.

Comment: `var script = //...`  would be a better solution. Declaring global variables pollutes the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple javascript to change the innerHtml of `document.head` will work

```
document.head.innerHTML = "<script src=\"jquery-1.8.0.min.js\"></script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var HeadScript = document.createElement("SCRIPT")
HeadScript.src = "jquery-1.8.0.min.js"
document.head.appendChild(HeadScript)
```